# Azure Data Studio An error occurred while loading file data

Tags: azure-data-studio

I am trying to restore my MSSQL database in Azure Data Studio. I right click the database, click restore, the change `Restore from` to `Backup File`. Then I click the 3 dots in the `Backup file path` and then it loads a while and gives me this error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You were trying to import the mssql database on the Azure. But it failed somehow. You need to delete the old database and create the new database, it will work.